# nth derivative of $e^{-x}\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying but no luck. Can't find a pattern yet.
The exercise is to find the nth derivative of $e^{-x}\sin(x)$ probably by induction.

Comment: Is the sine really in the exponent? (I would have expected $e^{-x}\sin x$ to which one could at least apply Leibniz' rule for $n$th derivative of a product.)

Comment: The edit is wrong.

Comment: Which edit is wrong? Now it looks like what I thought it should be (last comment), but it would be good of Gonzalo were to confirm the final version of the function.  A minute or two ago it had the sine in the exponent, at my site.

Comment: Look at the original post. http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/946280/revisions

Comment: I did it for $e^x \sin x$ [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659104/nth-derivative-of-ex-sin-x), it might be helpful. Try to mimic it.

Comment: Thanks, is the i just a normal variable or i as in sqrt(-1) ? Also the sine isn't the exponent, sorry this was my first question here and i'm note really familiar with it's format.

Comment: Hehe http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have $\sin z = \Im(e^{iz})$, hence:
$$\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left(e^{-z}\sin z\right)=\Im\left(\frac{d^n}{dz^n}e^{(i-1)z}\right)=\Im\left((i-1)^n e^{(i-1)z}\right)=2^{n/2}e^{-z}\,\Im\left(e^{i(z+3n\pi/4)}\right)$$
giving:
$$\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left(e^{-z}\sin z\right)=2^{n/2}e^{-z}\sin(z+3\pi n/4).$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer however I think I lack the knowledge to understand it. Why would sinz=integral of e^(iz) ?

Comment: @GonzaloFernández: $\Im$ stands for the imaginary part, not the integral.

Comment: Oh I see. Then i definitely lack the knowledge to comprehend this. Thank you anyways ;)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is an easier way.
Put $g(x)= e^{(-1+i)x}$ and note that your $f(x)$ is the imaginary part of $g(x)$ for real $x$. Now $g^{(n)}(x) =(-1+i)^n e^{(1+i)x}$.Now i am sure you can proceed further!

Comment: That's exactly the content of the answer below.

Comment: Ohh i see..actually i din't see your answer