# Prove $\sin^{(k)}{x}=\sin{\left(x+\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove $\sin^{(k)}{x}=\sin{\left(x+\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)}$

That means that the k-the derivative of $\sin{x}$ can be expressed this way. This seems to be a basic result, but I cannot find any reference to it and cannot see how to prove it on my own. Any hint?

Comment: Induction. ${}{}$

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752455/100-th-derivative-of-the-function-fx-ex-cosx/1752462#1752462

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. From De Moivre's formula, 
$$
e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x,
$$ one may differentiate $k$ times to get
$$
i^k \cdot e^{ix}=\cos^{(k)} x+i\sin^{(k)} x,
$$ then take the imaginary part, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, noticing that
$$
i=e^{i \pi/2}.
$$

Comment: but what to do with the cos? Don't see it...

Comment: You also get a formula for $\cos^{(k)} x$...

Comment: Observe that $i^k \cdot e^{ix}=e^{i(x+k\pi/2)}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin'(x) = \cos(x) = \sin(x+\frac\pi 2) $$
Now use induction on $k$ to find the higher derivatives.