# How to find $n^{th}$ derivative of $e^{2x}\cos^2x \sin x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given : $y=e^{2x} \times \cos^2x \times \sin x$ and I have to find it's $n^{th}$ derivative

I have managed to break $y$ down to:

$y= \frac{1}{4} \times (e^{2x}.\sin 3x + e^{2x}.\sin x)$

But I don't know how to apply Leibnitz Rule in cases like $(e^{ax} \times \sin bx)$.
 Please guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Hint:* Use the representation
>   \begin{align*}
> \cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\qquad\qquad \sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}
> \end{align*}
>   expand 
>   \begin{align*}
> y(x)=e^{2x}\cos^2(x)\sin(x)
> \end{align*}
>   and differentiate.

Alternative:

> Recall the *[general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)* and consider
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(e^{ax}\sin(bx)\right)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left(e^{ax}\right)\frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}}\left(\sin(bx)\right)
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$4y=2e^{2x}(1+\cos2x)\sin x=2e^{2x}\sin x+e^{2x}[\sin3x-\sin x]=e^{2x}\sin3x+e^{2x}\sin x$$

$e^{ax}\sin bx=$imaginary part of $$e^{x(a+ib)}$$

Now see [$100$-th derivative of the function $f(x)=e^{x}\cos(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752455/100-th-derivative-of-the-function-fx-ex-cosx/1752462#1752462)

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not very fluent with complex numbers. Kindly elaborate a bit?

Comment: @TheDeadLegend,  $a+ib$  essentially a constant being independent of $x$   $$\dfrac{d^n[e^{cx}]}{dx^n}=c^ne^{cx}$$

Answer (score 0):

$y= \dfrac{1}{4}  (e^{2x}\sin 3x + e^{2x}\sin x)=\dfrac{1}{4}{\bf Im}\left(e^{(2+3i)x} + e^{(2+i)x}\right)$
so
$$y^{(n)}= \dfrac{1}{4}{\bf Im}\left((2+3i)^ne^{(2+3i)x} + (2+i)^ne^{(2+i)x}\right)$$