# What will be the $n$th derivative of $y = e^{ax} \sin(ax+b)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

$$y = e^{ax} \sin(ax+b)$$

I tried finding a pattern but no luck till the 7th derivative, and I have seen some people solving it with Euler's method but I doubt my familiarity with it. It'd be great if someone could shed some light on a more straight-forward, general and intuitive solution to the problem.

Where a and b are constants.

Comment: a,b constants??

Comment: Have you tried writing $\sin(ax+b)$ as a sum of complex exponentials?

Comment: Hello, I think you are pointing out to Euler's formula which I am unaware of/not familiar with.

Comment: Euler's formula : $\forall t\in\mathbb R,\;\sin t = \dfrac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393139/how-to-find-nth-derivative-of-this-y/2393143#2393143

Comment: The  pattern is of period $8$. If you refuse to deal with complex numbers you'll never discern it.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter. "The shortest path to truth in $\mathbb R$ is through $\mathbb C$."--- Hadamard.

Comment: Indeed the complex approach allows to simplify massively the (rather non practical) approach suggested in the accepted answer and it has been explained in no answer below. But the OP is not interested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote by $f^{(n)}$ the $n$th derivative of $f$. One has the following:

**General Leibniz  Rule**: For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f,g$ two functions $n$ time differentiable, $fg$ is $n$ times differentiable and

$$(fg)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}.$$

Now all you need is to find the $n$th derivative of $e^{ax}$ and $\sin(ax+b)$.

Answer (score 3):

In a recursive scheme for $y^{(n)}$ we shall have to make room for the factor $e^{ax}$ and for $\sin(ax+b)$ as well for $\cos(ax+b)$ terms. We therefore write
$$y^{(n)}(x)=e^{ax}\bigl(A_n\cos(ax+b)+B_n\sin(ax+b)\bigr)\qquad(n\geq0)\tag{1}$$
with $A_0=0$, $B_0=1$. Differentiating $(1)$ leads to
$$\eqalign{A_{n+1}&=a(A_n+B_n)\cr B_{n+1}&=a(-A_n+B_n)\ .\cr}$$
These equations can be condensed to
$$A_{n+1}+i B_{n+1}=a(1-i)(A_n+iB_n)\ ,$$
so that
$$A_n+iB_n=a^n (1-i)^n\>i\qquad(n\geq0)\ .$$Now $1-i=\sqrt{2}e^{-i\pi/4}$, so that 
$$i(1-i)^n=2^{n/2}e^{(2-n)i\pi/4}\ .$$
This then implies
$$A_n=a^n\>2^{n/2}\cos{(n-2)\pi\over4},\qquad B_n=-a^n\>2^{n/2}\sin{(n-2)\pi\over 4}\qquad(n\geq0)\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

One formula to memorise:

$$D^n[e^{ax}.\sin(bx+c)]=(a^2+b^2)^{\frac{n}{2}} e^{ax}\sin(bx+c+n \tan^{-1}\frac{b}{a})$$

How to get that?

$$D^1=e^{ax}[a\sin(bx+c) + b\sin(bx+c+\pi/2)]$$

Let $a=r \cos\alpha, b=r\sin\alpha$ and $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Now put it in the equation above:
$$D^1=e^{ax} r\sin(bx+c+\alpha)$$
$$D^n=e^{ax}.r^n.\sin(bx+c+n\alpha)$$