# Writing a general formula for nth derivative of $\cos(ax)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, derivatives

So as stated in the title I have to create a general formula for nth derivative of $f(x) = \cos(ax)$ and proving it with induction.

I get $f(x) = \cos(ax)$

$f'(x) = -a\sin(ax)$

$f''(x) = -a^2\cos(ax)$

$f'''(x) = a^3\sin(ax)$

$f''''(x) = a^4\cos(ax)$

How are you supposed to algrebraically write a formula for this? I obviously see a pattern but I don't know how to approach this. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752455/100-th-derivative-of-the-function-fx-ex-cosx/1752462#1752462

Answer (score 1):

When $n=1$, you get $-a \sin ax$.
When $n=3$, you get $a^3 \sin ax$.
When $n=5$, you get $-a^5 \sin ax$.

So at each step you multiply by $-a^2$. So $f^{(n)} (x)=(-a^2)^{(n-1)/2}(-a)\sin ax,$ for $n$ odd.

When $n=0$, you get $ \cos ax$.
When $n=2$, you get $-a^2 \cos ax$.
When $n=4$, you get $a^4 \cos ax$.

So at each step you multiply by $-a^2$. So $f^{(n)} (x)=(-a^2)^{n/2}\cos ax,$ for $n$ even.

Comment: But for even derivatives according to your formula, would't the constant $a$ always be positive? At n =2 as an example.

Comment: @AliasaZarownyPseudonymia: I don't see where you see anything to that effect.

Comment: @AliasaZarownyPseudonymia $n=2$ would give $$f^{(n)}(x)=f^{(2)}(x)=(-a^2)^{2/2}\cos ax=-a^2 \cos ax$$ which is correct. Whether $a$ is positive or negative is not relevant. Does that clear up your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can write
$$
f(x)=\cos(ax)=\frac{e^{iax}+e^{-iax}}{2}
$$
so
$$
f^{(n)}(x)=a^n\frac{i^ne^{iax}+(-i)^ne^{-iax}}{2}
$$
Now observe that $i=e^{i\pi/2}$ and $-i=e^{-i\pi/2}$, so
$$
i^ne^{iax}=e^{i(ax+n\pi/2)}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
(-i)^n=e^{-i(ax+n\pi/2)}
$$
Finally you get
$$
f^{(n)}(x)=a^n\cos\left(ax+n\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$f^{(4k)}(x)=a^{4k}\cos(ax)$, $f^{(4k+1)}(x)=-a^{4k+1}\sin(ax)$, $f^{(4k+2)}(x)=-a^{4k+2}\cos(ax)$, $f^{(4k+3)}(x)=a^{4k+3}\sin(ax)$, $k=0,1,2,...$

Comment: What did you do to understand that you have to take n = 4k?

Comment: I don't follow? In principle I am considering the remainder of dividing by $4$, that the pattern has a loop after four trials, of course @John Doe provided a more efficient answer.

Comment: For some reason this is still a little confusing for me. Did you use 4k because the series repeats on the 4th multipel?

Comment: Yes, it repeats, as you can see for number fifth, sixth, ...

Comment: This might sound stupid. But I just want to affirm(sorry).  So what's the reason for including $k=0,1,2,3..$, is it just to say that for every positive integer $k$ it will return the same value?

Comment: Your comment sounds offensive. Actually if you look at the solution provided by @John Doe, when $n=2k$ is even, and he actually subdivided again to get $n/2=k$ but the sign $(-1)^{n/2}=(-1)^{k}$ still varies, and it becomes positive if $k$ is even and negative if $k$ is odd, and this is somehow subdividing $k$ again, in some sense for the original $n$, you subdivide twice, so it is something having to do with subdividing by $4$, which exactly is my solution going like. Of course I have to say his solution is more neatly than mine but I don't think my solution ought the title to be stupid.

Comment: I'm sorry if I unintentionally offended you! I meant that my question was stupid, not yours. I'm incredibly thankfull that somebody even engages me in an active dialogue just to help me figure things out. I would never willfully antagonize someone. Sorry and thank you btw

Answer (score 0):

In one formula it is
$$
f^{(k)}(x)=a^k\cos\left(ax+k\frac\pi2\right)
$$
using the symmetries of sine and cosine $\sin(x+\frac\pi2)=\cos(x)$ and $\cos(x+\frac\pi2)=-\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the obvious parts down and slowly work our way to the general derivative. Obviously$$f^{(n)}(x)=a^n\times\text{something}$$Where $f(x)=\cos ax$. To find what the 'something' is, we employ an old rule that$$\begin{align*} & \sin\left(x+\tfrac 12\pi\right)=\cos x\\ & \cos\left(x+\tfrac 12\pi\right)=\sin x\end{align*}$$Since $f(x)$ without a derivative is $\cos ax$, so we will be using the latter formula. And based off the rest of the observations, we can guess that$$f^{(n)}(x)=a^n\cos\left(ax+\tfrac 12 n\pi\right)$$For integral $n$.

---

Let's use induction to prove it. The first few steps (substituting $n=0$) will be left as an exercise for the OP, but the essential part is using$$f^{(n+1)}(x)=\left[f^{(n)}(x)\right]'$$Hence$$\begin{align*}f^{(n+1)}(x) & =\left[f^{(n)}(x)\right]'\\ & =-a^{n+1}\sin\left(ax+\tfrac 12n\pi\right)\\ & =a^{n+1}\cos\left(ax+\tfrac 12n\pi+\tfrac \pi2\right)\end{align*}$$
Where the last line follows from$$\cos\left(\theta+\frac {\pi}2\right)=-\sin\theta$$and $\theta$ is the expression inside the cosine function.