# Finding the tenth derivative of $f(x) = e^x\sin x$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I came across this Question where I have to find $$f^{(10)}$$ for the following function at $x = 0$ 
$$f(x) = e^x\sin x$$

I tried differentiating a few times to get a pattern but didn’t get one, can someone provide the solution.

Comment: Older questions about this (or very similar) problem: [$n$th derivative of $e^x \sin x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/659104) and [N derivative of function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1992070). Perhaps you can find a few more. Some useful tips on searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: "I tried differentiating a few times to get a pattern but didn’t get one" "A few times" meaning... what?

Comment: HNQ is broken. Exhibit: The present question.

Comment: Another related question: [$100$-th derivative of the function $f(x)=e^{x}\cos(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1752455).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Hint:

$$f(x)=e^x\sin x$$
$$f'(x)=e^x(\sin x +\cos x)$$
$$f''(x)=e^x(\sin x+\cos x)+e^x(\cos x -\sin x)=2e^x(\cos x)$$
$$f'''(x)=e^x(2\cos x)-e^x(2\sin x)=2e^x(\cos x-\sin x)$$
$$f^{IV}(x)=2e^x(\cos x-\sin x)-2e^x(\cos x+\sin x)=-4e^x(\sin x)=-4f(x)$$

Comment: First time to see roman numerals to denote derivatives. Nice!

Comment: Lower case too, awful notation if you ask me.

Comment: I have no problem with lowercase roman numerals in general, but here it looks like taking the power to the imaginary unit (times $v$)...

Comment: There will be some confusion when you get to the tenth derivative......

Comment: @Spencer And now you have me thinking about whether derivatives could be extended to the reals as exponents and factorials have been. Could it mean anything sane to take the 1.5th derivative?

Comment: @marshalcraft good point. I've edited to use capitals instead, given yours and Spencer's comments.

Comment: @Shufflepants https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus

Comment: Seems you would need some smaller more canonical notion of a derivative to have fractional nth derivatives. And them preferably a natural one which has some use maybe or maybe one with no useful application is more interesting.

Comment: Could just say take derivative a sub dominant interval, number of times. Hehe. (from music theory, not to confuse people reading)

Answer (score 72):

**Hint**:

As $\;\mathrm e^x\sin x=\operatorname{Im}\bigl(\mathrm e^{(1+i)x}\bigr)$, you have to find first the real and imaginary parts of $(1+i)^{10}$.

*Some details*:

There results from the above remark  and linearity of differentiation that $\;(\mathrm e^x\sin x)'=\bigl(\operatorname{Im}(\mathrm e^{(1+i)x})\bigr)'= \operatorname{Im}\bigl((1+i)\mathrm e^{(1+i)x}\bigr)$, hence
$$\;(\mathrm e^x\sin x)''=\bigl(\operatorname{Im}((1+i)\mathrm e^{(1+i)x}))\bigr)'= \operatorname{Im}\bigl((1+i)^2\mathrm e^{(1+i)x}\bigr),$$
and more generally
$$(\mathrm e^x\sin x)^{(k)}=\bigl(\operatorname{Im}(\mathrm e^{(1+i)x})\bigr)^{(k)}=\operatorname{Im}\bigl((1+i)^k(\mathrm e^{(1+i)x})\bigr).$$

Comment: This is by far the most efficient solution.

Comment: Knowing $(1+i)^2=2i$ helps too

Comment: This is an excellent hint, for students with a little knowledge of complex numbers.  It also can be followed by a second hint: don’t use binomial expansion to find these!

Comment: Could you please add a little more explanation? I can't understand how this method works.

Comment: @Abcd:  I've added some explanations. Is that clearer?

Comment: Not really I am afraid. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @Abcd: you don't have to be sorry. We're here to help as much as we can. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Bernard The very first  line, "You have to first find the real and imaginary parts of (1+i)^10"

Comment: @Abcd: What do you mean: you can't compute them, or you do not see what to do with them?

Comment: We will convert 1+ i to Euler's form right to get the imaginary part? ... So my question is "what to do with them"?

Comment: The tenth drivative of the complex-values function is $(1+i)^{10}\mathrm e^{(1+i)x}$. Calculate it (in exponential form), then extract the imaginary part. Is it clear now?

Comment: Very kind Bernard can you see my last question on Math.SE? I am Sebastiano of TeX.SE. :-)

Answer (score 18):

**Using power series**: it is well-known that $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ and $\sin(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$ for any real number $x$, so

$$ e^x\sin(x)=(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots+\frac{x^{10}}{10!}+\dots)(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}+\dots) $$

By expanding, the coefficient of $x^{10}$ is $\frac{1}{9!1!}-\frac{1}{7!3!}+\frac{1}{5!5!}-\frac{1}{7!3!}+\frac{1}{9!1!}$

But this coefficient is also $\frac{f^{(10)}(0)}{10!}$, so

$$ f^{(10)}(0)=\frac{10!}{9!1!}-\frac{10!}{7!3!}+\frac{10!}{5!5!}-\frac{10!}{7!3!}+\frac{10!}{9!1!} = 10 -120 + 252 - 120 +10 = 32$$

Comment: Take note of this solution, if the derivative at some point is needed, you don't need a symbolic expression for the $n$th derivative evaluated at some arbitrary point $x$. In some cases where a symbolic expression is not available, you can still find the $n$th derivative at some special point for arbitrary $n$. Also, there exists a general method based on Newton-Raphson division to find the $n$th derivative of an arbitrary function at some given point using some power of $\log(n)$ multiplications. Some computer algebra systems use such methods to compute series expansions.

Answer (score 10):

Use Leibniz' Rule for higher derivatives of a product:
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(uv)
  =\frac{d^nu}{dx^n}v+\binom n1\frac{d^{n-1}u}{dx^{n-1}}\frac{dv}{dx}
    +\binom n2\frac{d^{n-2}u}{dx^{n-2}}\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}+\cdots+u\frac{d^nv}{dx^n}\ .$$
In your case take $u=e^x$ and $v=\sin x$.  Since you are going to substitute $x=0$ after differentiating, all the $e^x$ terms will be $1$, all the $\sin x$ terms will be $0$ and all the cos $x$ terms will be $1$ (though some of them will pick up a negative sign when you differentiate).  So the answer is
$$\eqalign{0+\binom{10}11&{}+\binom{10}20+\binom{10}3(-1)+\binom{10}40+\binom{10}51\cr
  &\qquad{}+\binom{10}60+\binom{10}7(-1)+\binom{10}80+\binom{10}91+\binom{10}{10}0\cr
  &=10-120+252-120+10\cr
  &=32\ .\cr}$$

Answer (score 4):

One trick here is to use $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$ and define $g(x)=e^x\cos x$ then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both real functions.

Let $h(x)=g(x)+if(x)=e^{(1+i)x}$ then the tenth derivative of $h(x)$ is $(1+i)^{10}h(x)$ and the tenth derivative of $f(x)$ is the imaginary part of this.

Because you only want the value at $x=0$ you can evaluate there, with $h(0)=g(0)+if(0)$

Answer (score 4):

$$(e^x(a\cos x+b\sin x))'=e^x(a\cos x+b\sin x)+e^x(b\cos x-a\sin x)=e^x((a+b)\cos x+(b-a)\sin x).$$

So

$$(0,1)\to(1,1)\to(2,0)\to(2,-2)\to(0,-4)\to(-4,-4)\to(-8,0)\to(-8,8)\to(0,16)\to(16,16)\to(32,0).$$

---

If you divide by increasing powers of $2$, in pairs, the pattern emerges, with period $8$:

$$(0,1)\to(1,1)\to(1,0)\to(1,-1)\to(0,-1)\to(-1,-1)\to(-1,0)\to(-1,1)\to(0,1)\to(1,1)\to(1,0).$$

Answer (score 4):

I get $f^{10}(x)=32e^x\cos x$.

Here's what I did:

\begin{align}f'(x)&=e^x(\sin x+\cos x)\\
\implies f''(x)&=2e^x\cos x\\
\implies f^3(x)&=2e^x(\cos x-\sin x)\\
\implies f^4(x)&=2e^x(-2\sin x)=-4f(x)\\
\implies f^5(x)&=-4f'(x)\\
\implies f^8(x)&=-4f^4(x)=16f(x)\\
\implies f^{10}(x)&=16f''(x)\end{align}

Comment: Your calculation for $f^{(4)}$ is wrong. Looks like you missed a product rule.

Comment: Be careful: $$(e^x(g(x))'=e^xg(x)+e^xg'(x)$$ You missed the first bit in your calculation for $f^4$

Comment: @RhysHughes &Alexander J93  thanks

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the question about looking for a pattern:

Repeated application of the product rule gives

$$ f(x) = e^x \sin x$$
$$ f'(x) = e^x \sin x + e^x \cos x$$
$$ f''(x) = e^x \sin x + e^x \cos x + e^x \cos x - e^x \sin x = 2\ e^x \cos x$$
Is a pattern emerging?
$$ f^{(3)}(x) = 2\ e^x \cos x -2\ e^x \sin x$$
$$ f^{(4)}(x) = 2\ e^x \cos x -2\ e^x \sin x - 2\ e^x \sin x - 2\ e^x \cos x = -4\ e^x \sin x$$
Yes. We can then conclude that

$ f^{(6)}(x) = -8\ e^x \cos x$, $f^{(8)}(x) = 16\ e^x \sin x$, and $f^{(10)}(x) = 32\ e^x \cos x$

such that $f^{(10)}(0) = 32 $

Answer (score 3):

Use the formula $(fg)^{(n)}= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom {n} {k} (f)^{(k)}(g)^{(n-k)}$.

Answer (score 2):

Using recurrence relation:
$$\begin{align}f^{(0)}=&e^x\sin x\\
f^{(1)}=&e^x\sin x+e^x\cos x=f^{(0)}+e^x\cos x\\
f^{(2)}=&f^{(1)}+\color{red}{e^x\cos x}-e^x\sin x=f^{(1)}+\color{red}{f^{(1)}-f^{(0)}}-f^{(0)}\\
\color{blue}{f^{(n)}=}&\color{blue}{2f^{(n-1)}-2f^{(n-2)}, f^{(0)}(0)=0, f^{(1)}(0)=1} \Rightarrow \\
f^{(n)}=&\frac12i\left[(1-i)^n-(1+i)^n\right] \Rightarrow \\
f^{(10)}(0)=&\frac12i[(1-i)^{10}-(1+i)^{10}]=\\
=&-\frac12i\left[{10\choose 1}i+{10\choose 3}i^3+{10\choose 5}i^5+{10\choose 7}i^7+{10\choose 9}i^9\right]=\\
=&{10\choose 1}-{10\choose 3}+{10\choose 5}-{10\choose 7}+{10\choose 9}=\\
=&10-120+252-120+10=\\
=&32.\end{align}$$

---

**Addendum:** Direct calculation from the recurrence relation above:
$$\color{blue}{f^{(n)}=2\left[f^{(n-1)}-f^{(n-2)}\right], f^{(0)}(0)=0, f^{(1)}(0)=1}\\
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
f^{(0)}&f^{(1)}&f^{(2)}&f^{(3)}&f^{(4)}&f^{(5)}&f^{(6)}&f^{(7)}&f^{(8)}&f^{(9)}&f^{(10)}\\
\hline
0&1&2&2&0&-4&-8&-8&0&16&32\end{array}$$